# Python Intra-Package Imports - How do I get common functions/classes spread throughout my package?

Tags: python

I have a set of python scripts organized like so:

```
PythonScripts/
     TypeAScripts/
        TypeASet1Scripts/
            example.py
        TypeASet2Scripts/
     TypeBScripts/
        TypeBSet1Scripts/
        TypeBSet2Scripts/
     TypeCScripts/
        TypeCSet1Scripts/
        TypeCSet2Scripts/
     CommonFunctions/
        CommonFunctions.py
```

with `init.py` in every folder. What I want is to be able to run `example.py` where `example.py` imports from `CommonFunctions`. I want scripts throughout folders A,B, and C to do the same.

To do this with absolute imports, you'd put

```
 import PythonScripts.CommonFunctions.CommonFunctions
```

However, this only works if `PythonScripts` is in your python path. Which, if you are just running `example.py` in that folder, isn't going to be the case. You can add it with `sys.append()`, but this seems like an awkward way of doing it. Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 1):

Python supports relative imports, but in my experience they're finicky and don't do what you would expect them to do. You can find more information about them in [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).

I would suggest properly packaging your modules and writing a `setup.py` file to install them into the global site-packages directory. This will allow you to reference your modules from anywhere on the system using absolute imports and additionally provides you the option of registering them with the [Python Package Index (PyPi)](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) for distribution to third parties. A good tutorial on how to do this is ["The Hitchhiker's Guide to Packaging 1.0"](http://guide.python-distribute.org/quickstart.html#lay-out-your-project).

Additionally, if you're concerned about borking your global site-packages directory I'd suggest you do your test installs in a [Python virtual environment](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/). The [`virtualenv`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) tool in particular makes working with virtual environments simple.